# Validate form fields using form wizard in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to validate form input fields in multistep form, my code:

```js
import { FormWizard, TabContent, ValidationHelper } from "vue-step-wizard";
import "vue-step-wizard/dist/vue-step-wizard.css";
import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
import { email } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
import { numeric } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
```

```js
mixins: [ValidationHelper],
data() {
    return {
        form: new Form({
            fullName:"",
        }),
        validationRules: [
            { fullName: { required } },
        ]
    };
},
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined
```

Comment: What is `new Form`? The [docs](https://tushargugnani.github.io/vue-step-wizard/#/?id=form-data) say this: "All the form fields (from all the steps), needs to be defined inside a dedicated object named `formData`"

Comment: @Daniel_Knights:Thanks, after changing form with formData now validation is working